# Connection freeze to SQL server via PYMSSQL version 2.2.8

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy, connection, pymssql

When connecting to SQL with Python it freezes on connection using pymssql, no error, no timeout, just hang there

```
database_connection = f"mssql+pymssql://{_USERNAME_}:{_PASSWORD_}@{_SERVER_}:{_PORT_}/{_DATABASE_}"
engine = create_engine(database_connection)
connection = engine.connect()
```

**What helped me, was uninstalling pymssql version 2.2.8 and using version 2.2.7**

Comment: It's not our place to speculate about bugs and issues in a vendor's tools. Have you started with a Google search? e.g.: `"2.2.8" inurl:https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues`

Comment: Yes, i tried that. And create new bug report https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/842, then i will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I cannot comment as I am a nooob.

Please see the TDSDUMP piece on https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Specifically, you need to add to your code before the connection attempt:

```
import os
os.environ['TDSDUMP'] = 'stdout'
```

This will not fix your problem, but at least it will print out into the terminal some clues as to what's going on. Please then "edit" your question to include that dump being careful to redact any sensitive info.